# Articles on Music Festivals/Fairs/Tradeshows

Tags: books

I'm doing a research on the effects of music events on creative industries but there is a very limited number of sources - was wondering if I could get some recommendations (books, articles, etc...)

For example I would like some figures and facts of, for instance, music fairs, festivals, etc... that happened in the recent years. Articles that speak about how music fairs, festivals have benefited the music industry and how it facilitated the development of the music industry.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  This sounds like it would result in an itemized list.  Please refer to the section on lists [here](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/161/community-wiki-list-recommendation-questions-and-you/162#162) and revise if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the most influential music show in the USA is NAMM:
"NAMM, National Association of Music Merchants"

Everyone from Fender to Yamaha, both musical instruments and recording industry want to show off here. Impact is far reaching as distributors clamor to see the latest gadgets and improvements. Any articles regarding NAMM would be significant for your research.

Links to start with:

http://www.nammfoundation.org/music-research

http://www.namm.org/news/press-releases/namm-foundation-awards-848807-support-innovative-m

http://www.namm.org/library

Consider that Fender, Gibson, PRS, Yamaha, Martin, and the lot spend millions on advertising hence they need to do their homework on who to reach and how. Any marketing info from these companies would be significant in understanding how festivals, fairs, and tradeshows have impact on their sales.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [one idea I had](http://articles.cnn.com/2004-08-13/us/twih.woodstock_1_max-yasgur-free-concert-music-festival?_s=PM%3aUS), it's about Woodstock, sorry if it's a shot in the dark but it should help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Look for resources in the field of [arts management](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=arts%20management&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). That link is to a Google search on the term.

By all means, read [Pollstar](http://www.pollstar.com/) and [Billboard](http://www.billboard.com/) magazines, and research their archives.